# on selected value of radio button get html form

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have two registration HTML form for **Student** and **College** .
Initially, I have two radio buttons of Student and College. If I select Student I'll get student registration form or if I select College I'll get college registration form also I want to insert that value of radio button to the database. I'm unable to understand how should I start. I'm using PHP and MySQLi technology. Please help me with this?

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <h5>Whether College/Student?</h5>
    <div class="form-group form-check-inline">
        <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input id="radio" name="radio" value="0" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="custom-control-description">College</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-check-inline">
        <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input id="radio" name="radio" value="1" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="custom-control-description">Student</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't do this in php, you need to use ajax for it

Comment: then how can use ajax for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need a form. You can read this article to understand how to do this and how get your form values with [form tutorial](http://php.net/manual/fr/tutorial.forms.php)

After you'll need to put those values in a database. To do that i recommand you [PDO](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.pdo.php)

But you probably should practice withsome tutorial before did you try to do [this one](https://www.formget.com/php-mysqli-insert/)?